# Using AVA with PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs, ava

I am trying to run some test over a webpage using AVA and PhantomJS (actually phantomjs-node)

I have to files, first one is a module that loads a webpage using Phantom (load-page.js)

```
    const phantom = require('phantom');

    /**
     * Loads a page using a Promise and jsdom
     * @param {string} url The page to be loaded
     */
    export default function loadPage(url, callback, thenCallback) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const instance = await phantom.create();
            const page = await instance.createPage();

            const status = await page.open('https://webslides.tv/');
            if(status != 'success') reject('Error loading '+url);

            await page
                .evaluate(callback)
                .then(await thenCallback);

            await instance.exit();

            resolve(true);
        });
    }
```

The second one is the test:

```
    import test from 'ava';
    import loadPage from '../helpers/load-page';

    test('prueba', async t => {
        const check = count => {
            t.is(count.childNodes.length, 9);
        }
        await loadPage('http://webslides.tv', () => {
            const ws = document.querySelector('#webslides');
            return ws;
        }, async (count) => {
            await check(count);
        });
    });
```

Is it possible to run the tests once the page has been loaded? I want to run several tests with the same page, but I wouldn't like to load the page each time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your helper to not evaluate anything. Then you could reuse the page instance:

```js
import test from 'ava';
import loadPage from '../helpers/load-page';

let page;

test.before(async t => {
    page = await loadPage('http://webslides.tv');
});

test('prueba', async t => {
    const count = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const ws = document.querySelector('#webslides');
        return ws;
    });

    t.is(count.childNodes.length, 9);
});
```